# Dynamically choose .NET version

Tags: c#, .net

We have a software wrote in WinForms using .NET 4.0. Now we decided to upgrade our software to .NET 4.6. We wonder is there any posibillity to dynamically choose version of .NET which we want to use? 
It means we have new clients who will use new version of software but also we have the old customers who still use our software with .NET 4.0.
We can prepare version for .NET 4.6 and try to expire the old version but is there any posibillity to have one application running on different .NET version depending on customers enviroment? e.g. during implementation we're saying 
"use 4.6" and it uses .NET 4.6 or we say "use 4.0" and it uses .NET 4.0.

Comment: When you say that you decided to upgrade your software to .NET 4.6, do you mean the version you are *targeting* in the project? Or do you mean the version you are installing on a server? or the version you are distributing on a CD or download?  Please be more specific.  Also you should read up on .NET version targeting and backwards compatibility between versions.

Comment: I mean targeting, sorry.

Comment: It is already "dynamic".  In your project you select the *minimum* version of .NET that your user has to have installed.  It will force an update if it is less.  The actual version it runs with is the one that is present on the machine.

Comment: But it's not about installed version on client computer but about version in code. I want to have one code which will be running on .net 4.0 or .net 4.6.

Comment: Two different code bases means two different executables. The installer then can choose which one to install based on the requirements met in the client site.

Comment: Target version (4.0 and above) has only to do with the APIs available - not with the installed runtime. Do you need to use an API from 4.6? If not, just keep your code targeting 4.0. Clients can upgrade their runtime, or not,  and your code will still work.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5

That link talks about something similar. See it it helps/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow.  Please provide a summary.